# https://github.com/oarrabi/phoenix_facebook_echo_bot doesn't work on Elixir 1.3.3 with Phoenix 1.2.1

Tags: facebook, elixir, phoenix-framework

when I run mix phoenix.server under elixir 1.3.3 and phoenix 1.2.1, I got this error:

```
paul@learning:~/elixir/phoenix_facebook_echo_bot$ mix phoenix.server
==> httpotion
Compiling 1 file (.ex)

== Compilation error on file lib/httpotion.ex ==
** (ArgumentError) Access is not a protocol
    (elixir) lib/protocol.ex:76: Protocol.assert_protocol!/2
    lib/httpotion.ex:292: (module)
    (stdlib) erl_eval.erl:670: :erl_eval.do_apply/6

could not compile dependency :httpotion, "mix compile" failed. You can recompile this dependency with "mix deps.compile httpotion", update it with "mix deps.update httpotion" or clean it with "mix deps.clean httpotion"
```

I tried to follow the advice from: myfreeweb/httpotion#87

Then when I do mix deps.update --all, then I got the following errors:

```
paul@learning:~/elixir/phoenix_facebook_echo_bot$ mix deps.update --all
Running dependency resolution

Failed to use "httpotion" (versions 3.0.0 to 3.0.2) because
  facebook_messenger (versions 0.2.0 and 0.3.0) requires ~> 2.2
  mix.exs specifies ~> 3.0.0

Failed to use "poison" (version 2.2.0) because
  phoenix (version 1.2.1) requires ~> 1.5 or ~> 2.0
  phoenix_facebook_messenger (versions 0.1.0 and 0.3.0) requires ~> 2.1.0

** (Mix) Hex dependency resolution failed, relax the version requirements of your dependencies or unlock them (by using mix deps.update or mix deps.unlock). If you are unable to resolve the conflicts you can try overriding with {:dependency, "~> 1.0", override: true}
```

Please advise what shall I do to fix this "looping dependency error"?

Comment: Try `rm -rf _build && mix compile`

Answer (score 1):

[`Access`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/1.0.5/Access.html) was a [`protocol`](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/v1.0.5/lib/elixir/lib/access.ex#L1) before `Elixir 1.0.5` inclusive. Starting with `Elixir 1.1.0`, [`Access`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/1.1.0/Access.html) was changed to be a [`behaviour`](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/v1.1.0/lib/elixir/lib/access.ex#L1).

`phoenix_facebook_echo_bot` requires `HTTPotion` version 2. The latter in turn was built on top of Elixir 1.0, expecting `Access` to be a *`protocol`*.

The only easy option for you to run the code would be to install Elixir `v1.0.5` and use it to play with this package.

Other option would be to clone the package, as well as `facebook_messenger` package it relates on and *change their `mix.exs` files to require `HTTPotion` version 3`* and try to run (I don’t guarantee the success.)